# Is there a way of getting TFS Cross-Platform Command-Line Client working without using basic authentication?

Tags: linux, tfs

If have configured Team Explorer Everywhere 2015 [TEE-CLC-14.0.1] on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with the goal in mind to connect to a TFS server (12.0.31101.0  Tfs2013.Update4)
I have attempted to create a workspace by using the following command :
./tf workspace -new TFS_UNIX -collection:http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/MyCollection

After being prompted for my credentials I have entered my NT user account and password. This account has collection and project administrator permissions.

I then ended up with this error message:
An error occurred: The SOAP endpoint http:// mytfsserver:8080/tfs/mycollection/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted.  HTTP status: 403

[image]

Authentication mode on the TFS server is currently set to NTLM over http.

From what I have read a way to get around this is by reverting to basic authentication in IIS on the TFS application server.
Which then in turn brings some unsavoury security side effects.

Is there a way of getting this working while still maintaining an acceptable security setup?

EDIT:
I attempted the same procedure with a different collection with the same result (403).
In Visual Studio creating the workspace works with no problems.

[image]

Comment: Switching to basic isn't likely to solve this problem anyway.  A 403 isn't an auth problem.  What does the server say about this connection?  Are there any IIS rules that limit connections by IP?  Can you try a different collection than `binck`?  Can you show a screenshot of the server list when successfully connecting to this server from Visual Studio?

Comment: I tried a different collection but it delivered the same result. The creation of workspaces to the collection works fine in Visual studio.
After spending some time with the Network department it seemed that all traffic was blocked by the firewall :- (
That was adjusted and it is now possible to telnet from the Ubuntu server to the TFS server.
The ./tf workspace command however still returns a 403. So for now IIS is the next suspect. To be continued…
Thank you for the leads Edward !

Comment: Try to clean cache folder under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\_tfs_data, and re-install the TEE to see whether it helps.